# Why does Android Emulator shows only a blank Page?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I have recently installed AS with react Native and Node. When I start the Emulator it builds the Page. But in the Emulator itself it shows me only a blank React Page. In the Center is square but the square is blank too. 
Have I forgotten to install something?

Another short question:
When I want to create Applications with React Native do I need to get the ultimate Edition of Intellij? All the created .js pages are red and AS show the message that .js can only be used with the ultimate Edition.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();

        this.state = {
        todoInput: "",
        todos: [
        {id: 0, title: "Take out the trahs", done:false},
        {id: 1, title: "Cook dinner", done: false}
        ]
       }

     }



 render() {
  const statusbar = (Platform.OS == "android") ? <View style=    {styles.statusbar}></View> : <View></View>;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {statusbar}
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',

  },
  statusbar: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFCE00",
    height:20
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure Platform.OS == "android" is returning true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not an empty page. Your view is in the status bar area. The color of the status bar area  was changed. The start of the view starts at the top of the device because you have not located the flex value or the child's view.

If you set the value of `justifyContent` to the center like my answer, you will see the view you set.

```js
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    justifyContent:"center"

  },
```